# Show element after animation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want that after click to `TextView` show animation after that (after animation) show some modal window. How I may do this? P.s. My animation contained in XML file in `<animation-list>`

```
public class ExerciseWithExplain1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button solution;
    private TextView txtVWRed, explainForTable, solExplain, nextScreen, falseRow53, falseRow54, falseRow55, falseRow56, falseRow46, trueRow45, trueRow44, falseRow43, trueRow36, trueRow35, falseRow34, trueRow33, trueRow23, falseRow23, trueRow25, trueRow24, falseRow24, falseRow25, falseRow26, falseRow33, trueRow34, falseRow35, falseRow36, trueRow43, falseRow44, falseRow45, trueRow46, trueRow53, trueRow54, trueRow55, trueRow56, trueRow26;
    LinearLayout layForTable;
    AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    Context context;
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
    ImageView animImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_with_explain1);
        trueRow23 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow23);
        falseRow23 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow23);
        falseRow24 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow24);
        trueRow24 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow24);
        trueRow25 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow25);
        falseRow25 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow25);
        trueRow26 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow26);
        falseRow26 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow26);
        falseRow33 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow33);
        trueRow33 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow33);
        trueRow34 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow34);
        falseRow34 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow34);
        falseRow35 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow35);
        trueRow35 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow35);
        falseRow36 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow36);
        trueRow36 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow36);
        trueRow43 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow43);
        falseRow44 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow44);
        falseRow45 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow45);
        falseRow43 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow43);
        trueRow44 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow44);
        trueRow45 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow45);
        trueRow46 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow46);
        falseRow46 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow46);
        trueRow53 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow53);
        trueRow54 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow54);
        trueRow55 = findViewById(R.id.trueRow55);
        trueRow56 =findViewById(R.id.trueRow56);
        falseRow53 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow53);
        falseRow54 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow54);
        falseRow55 = findViewById(R.id.falseRow55);
        falseRow56 =findViewById(R.id.falseRow56);

        animImage = findViewById(R.id.animImage);
        animImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_mark);
        animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) animImage.getBackground();

        context = ExerciseWithExplain1.this;
        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        ad.setTitle(R.string.explainLogic);
        ad.setMessage(R.string.logicForAnd);
        final int ir = 0;
        falseRow56.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    animationDrawable.start();
                    ad.show();
            }
        });
        trueRow56.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animationDrawable.start();
            }
        });
        falseRow55.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animationDrawable.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try it by using Custom AnimationDrwable

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;

public abstract class CustomAnimationDrawableNew extends AnimationDrawable {

/** Handles the animation callback. */
Handler mAnimationHandler;

public CustomAnimationDrawableNew(AnimationDrawable aniDrawable) {
    /* Add each frame to our animation drawable */
    for (int i = 0; i < aniDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
        this.addFrame(aniDrawable.getFrame(i), aniDrawable.getDuration(i));
    }
}

@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    /*
     * Call super.start() to call the base class start animation method.
     * Then add a handler to call onAnimationFinish() when the total
     * duration for the animation has passed
     */
    mAnimationHandler = new Handler();
    mAnimationHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onAnimationStart();
        }
    });
    mAnimationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onAnimationFinish();
        }
    }, getTotalDuration());

}

/**
 * Gets the total duration of all frames.
 *
 * @return The total duration.
 */
public int getTotalDuration() {

    int iDuration = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
        iDuration += this.getDuration(i);
    }

    return iDuration;
}

/**
 * Called when the animation finishes.
 */
public abstract void onAnimationFinish();
/**
 * Called when the animation starts.
 */
public abstract void onAnimationStart();
```

}

Now Use it like this code.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iv_testing_testani);

tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        // Pass our animation drawable to our custom drawable class
        CustomAnimationDrawableNew cad = new CustomAnimationDrawableNew(
                (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.anim_test)) {
            @Override
            void onAnimationStart() {
                // Animation has started...
            }

            @Override
            void onAnimationFinish() {
                // Animation has finished...
            }
        };

        // Set the views drawable to our custom drawable
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(cad);

        // Start the animation
        cad.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: explain me please. How or where I may use your last chapter of code? I create abstract class and I don't know what must do next. I am junior in android/java

Comment: Okay,I have edited code please check and if you still don't get feel free to comment i will simplify more.Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I have some question about your code, but I will try find answer myself, because you did so much for me.